# Trying to align text in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to dynamically create an unconventional bar chart (I think that's how to describe it, please correct me with better terminology if possible!)

Here is an example I'm trying to recreate

[image: Example]

I'm struggling to include and align the text elements either side of the bar within my code. Here is my code and a plnk below;

The offending code;

```
function loadBars() {

var start_val = 0;

d3.select("body").selectAll(".barChart")
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.skill
    })

d3.select("body").selectAll(".pathBar")
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 200;
    })

.duration(1000)
    .style("width", function(d, i) {
        return d.progress * 0.6 + "%";
    })

d3.select("body").selectAll(".pathBar")
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.progress
    })
```

Plnk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sneKYhTPAK0X8IhhExj9?p=preview

I would also like the number to appear once the animation has finished, but one problem at a time!

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious here, I am new to using d3.js and everything is still confusing for me.

I hope I've explained the problem enough, but please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Comment: I would use rect rather than div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Firstly, working Plnk: http://plnkr.co/edit/vZYLTY5FEfpDmUw2f0sj?p=preview

---

### Explanation:

Your code generated the following HTML for each bar:

```
<div class="barResultsContainer">
    <div class="barChart">
        <div class="pathBar" style="width: 60%;">
            <div></div>
            <text>100</text>
        </div>
        <!-- Your text is AFTER your bar -->
        <text>AngularJS</text>
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you look at the generated bars, they're taking up a lot of width:

[image]

So I changed the Javascript code to put the text *first*, and I changed the CSS so that you could arrange it nicely. I also put all the bar graph generating logic into the `loadBars()` function ;)

Comment: Ah well explained - I can see where I was going wrong, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with the texts after the bars (based on Martin's Plunker):

http://plnkr.co/edit/9FMNDrYnBJdZ2YHqplzc?p=preview

Basically, I created another class for the texts:

```
.pathBarText {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  height: 18px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}
```